# Note-taking tool with extended functionality

Tags: web-apps, cross-platform, note-taking, reminders

I am seeking for a note-taking tool with the following functionality:

1. Extended formatting features
2. Sharing of any page/web-fragment (in screenshot or text form, with attaching URL and comment) to another person via multiple ways (Facebook, Google+, email, etc)
3. Recurring alarms. Ability to set alarm on a regular (daily, monthly, weekly) alarms.
4. Platform independence and web-version presence.

Evernote lacks the 3rd point and the 2nd is also limited.
2nd point is obligatory.

Comment: Should it be free/commercial/open-source? Which extended formatting features do you need: tables/images/categories/...? Local storage/cloud based?

Comment: 1. Free, open-source, commercial - it doesn't matter. But I dont like subscriptions and, BTW, open-source is preferable.  2. All extended formatting features you mentioned are important for me: tables, text formatting, images.  3. It should be cloud-based of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, I finally chose MS OneNote. It perfectly covers all the above requirements.

Answer (score 4):

This probably boils down to a matter of taste as there are quite a few software products out there that do more or less what you are looking for.

I'd recommend [Simplenote](http://simplenote.com/), but see further down for other alternatives.

## Simplenote:

- Extended formatting features through markdown support. See [here](http://techrageous.blogspot.ch/2013/03/how-to-get-started-with-markdown-format.html) for how this is done.
- Allows you to share your notes with others. See [here](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/12/20/advanced-simplenote-collaborating-blog-posts-and-advanced-applications/) for how this is done. And for web related content see [this](http://advocatesstudio.com/2011/10/03/syncing-with-simplenote/) approach.
- Support for alarms and reminder.
- Platform independence as it runs in the browser.

---

Here are a few alternatives:

- [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/) might be short on the 1. point, since e.g. markdown is not supported.
- [Simplenote](http://simplenote.com/) very similar to wunderlist but with markdown support. *This product is probably the best for your requirements.*

If you wan to go with something open source then there are:

- [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html) not the prettiest but gets the job done.
- [nixNote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) is a clone of Evernote but has a simple alarm function.
- [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/) together with Dropbox, owncloud or seafile. This project seems very promising but is still in development phase. I'd say it's worth keeping an eye on.

Hope this list helped.

PS. [alternativeto](http://alternativeto.net/) is a nice web page to find alternative products to a software that does not exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried Simplenote and refused from it because of its poor formatting abilities. Even bold wasn't supported and they didn't want to implement it (I had conversation with devs).

Comment: Hi @Suncatcher. Simplenote supports markdown. [Here](http://techrageous.blogspot.ch/2013/03/how-to-get-started-with-markdown-format.html) is a link that should get you started with using markdown.

Comment: Hence it has simple formatting, it lacks #2. Which is very critical for me.

Comment: What concerns Wunderlist, I see it cannot share Web-fragments. Can it?

Comment: What do you mean by web-fragments? HTML? A screenshot?

Comment: Simplenote can share notes, see `Sharing your notes, with a twist` on [here](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/12/20/advanced-simplenote-collaborating-blog-posts-and-advanced-applications/)

Comment: Web-fragment is an any piece of text on any page. And for those pages which are build using more distinguished technology than HTML (Flash, Silvernote, etc) screenshot capturing tool is highly appreciated (like Snipping Tool in Windows). [Evernote Web Clipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en) can do this

Comment: Simplenote can share notes, but it cannot save web-text to notes.

Comment: [Here](http://advocatesstudio.com/2011/10/03/syncing-with-simplenote/) is how to refer to and share web-content.

Comment: Wunderlist is not an option for me as it cannot create simple text notes - only lists.

Answer (score 0):

## [Todoist](https://todoist.com/)

While mainly a checklist app, I also use it for taking notes due to its features.

1. It provides extended formatting: **bold**, *italics*, and hyperlinks ([source](https://todoist.com/Help/TextFormatting))
2. Ability to attach notes in forms of text comments, files, or URLs to each task. Sharing with others is only possible via email or username. It's possible to assign multiple collaborators on the same project ([source](https://todoist.com/Help/Sharing))
3. Ability to easily set up reccurring reminders using phrases such as "every friday at 5pm" or "every month starting 25 Feb" ([source1](https://todoist.com/Help/Reminders))([source2](https://todoist.com/Help/DatesTimes))
4. Cross-platform with apps for Android, iOS, Chrome, Firefox, Windows, MacOS, web, and others ([source](https://todoist.com/Help/Apps))

Note that many features (such as file sharing) are restricted in the free version

Comment: Reminders is a [premium feature](https://todoist.com/Help/Reminders)  Aren't they?

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes. The free version is very limited. You have not specified a budget in the question so I assumed anything goes

Comment: Yeah, right) I didn't specified budget. But I don't like subscription, I like to pay once for a lifetime.

Comment: @Suncatcher I agree. I also try to avoid subscriptions, but this one worked for me and I couldn't find a good alternative. So I'm also interested in further answers. I have also posted [a meta question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1081/6834) to try and come up with a tag for such cases